# Convert a string date range to separate start and stop dates in R

Tags: r, date, range, stringr

I have a dataset (8000 observations) that has a string date variable. I would like to split the variable into StartDt and EndDt of format "%B %d %Y". The variable also spans calendar years eg Dec 30 to Jan 5 2019. I have not had success trying to use the stringr package and manipulate accordingly - appreciate any insights!

```
Df<-data.frame(Date2=c("Dec 16 to 22 2018","Dec 23 to 29 2018", "Dec 30 to Jan 5 2019"))
```

Comment: Could there also be a date in the same year but different months like `Apr 15 to May 20 2018`

Comment: @Ronak yes the data is by week and can span months

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_match` with regex and capture the values needed from the string. Pattern with `?` means they are optional.

```
#extract the data in a dataframe based on pattern
dat <- as.data.frame(stringr::str_match(Df$Date2, '([A-Za-z]+)\\s(\\d+)\\sto\\s?([A-Za-z]+)?\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)')[, -1])
#Change the columns to respective type
dat <- type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE)
#Copy the year column
dat$V6 <- dat$V5
#Copy the month column if it is the same
dat$V3[is.na(dat$V3)] <- dat$V1[is.na(dat$V3)]
#Subtract 1 from the year only if the End month is earlier than Start month
dat <- transform(dat, V5 = V5 - as.integer(match(V1, month.abb) > match(V3, month.abb)))

#Create the final result dataframe pasting the values
result <- data.frame(Start = with(dat, paste(V1, V2, V5)), 
                     End   = with(dat, paste(V3, V4, V6)))
result

#        Start         End
#1 Dec 16 2018 Dec 22 2018
#2 Dec 23 2018 Dec 29 2018
#3 Dec 30 2018  Jan 5 2019
#4 Apr 15 2018 May 20 2018
```

**data**

Added an additional date (`"Apr 15 to May 20 2018"`) in the input for testing purpose.

```
Df <- data.frame(Date2=c("Dec 16 to 22 2018","Dec 23 to 29 2018", 
                         "Dec 30 to Jan 5 2019", "Apr 15 to May 20 2018"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit long perhaps, but this will require a few steps, though it does only use vectorized functions:

```r
library(glue)
library(stringr)
Df<-data.frame(Date2=c("Dec 16 to 22 2018","Dec 23 to 29 2018", "Dec 30 to Jan 5 2019"))

## a regular expression to match abbreivated month names:
mnthrx <- paste0( "(?:", paste( month.abb, collapse="|" ), ")" )

## the big regex we will use to match it all:
rx <- glue( "({mnthrx}) (\\d+) to (?:({mnthrx}) )?(\\d+) (\\d+)" )

m <- str_match( Df$Date2, rx )

## The end date:
day2 <- as.integer(m[,5])
month2 <- m[,4]
year2 <- as.integer( m[, ncol(m)])

## The start date:
day1 <- m[,3]
month1 <- m[,2]
year1 <- year2

## if month2 is missing, its because we're in month1 still
j <- is.na(month2)
month2[j] <- month1[j]

month.number1 <- match( month1, month.abb )
month.number2 <- match( month2, month.abb )

## if month2 is smaller than month1, we swapped years:
i.next.year <- month.number2 < month.number1
year1[i.next.year] <- year2[i.next.year]-1

data.frame(
    StartDt = paste( month1,day1,year1, sep=" " ),
    EndDt = paste( month2,day2,year2, sep=" " )
)
```

It produces this:

```r
      StartDt       EndDt
1 Dec 16 2018 Dec 22 2018
2 Dec 23 2018 Dec 29 2018
3 Dec 30 2018  Jan 5 2019
```